# How to debug unexpected OpenBMC hwmon AST2600 behavior?

Tags: debugging, openbmc

I am debugging a pwmtachtool<->hwmon interaction problem, observed when OpenBMC image is running
on an AST2600 EVB, which is connected to a SensorsBoard and a Fan (Host is not connected).
The running OpenBMC image was built using bitbake, and it includes recipes-phosphor/configuration/entity-manager/SensorBoard.json,
customized for this SensorBoard. Verified that I2C sensors on the SensorsBoard are accessible via i2ctools,
and behave as expected. However, running "pwmtachtool <dev_id> --get-fan-speed <fan_num>" consistently
reports "Fan speed is 0", even though phy Fan is properly connected.
For example:

/usr/local/bin/pwmtachtool 0 --get-fan-speed 0 --verbose

GET_TACH_SPEED:rpm value 0

Fan 0 speed is 0

cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan0_input

0

Looking closely at the pwmtachtool codepath, I am seeing that it calls pwmtach_action(), which reads
"/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon<dev_id>/fan", which is always 0. Tried all <dev_id>/ combinations,
exposed by sysfs: same result. So far, unable to figure out why this is so.
I would really appreciate all recommendations for how to debug this problem.

Additional details:

ll /sys/class/hwmon/

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 16 08:52 hwmon0 -> ../../devices/platform/ahb/ahb:apb/1e610000.pwm-tacho-controller/hwmon/hwmon0

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 16 08:52 hwmon1 -> ../../devices/platform/iio-hwmon/hwmon/hwmon1

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 26 22:20 hwmon2 -> ../../devices/platform/ahb/ahb:apb/ahb:apb:bus@1e78a000/1e78a480.i2c-bus/i2c-8/8-004d/hwmon/hwmon2

ll /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/*

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device -> ../../../1e610000.pwm-tacho-controller

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan0_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan10_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan11_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan12_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan13_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan14_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan15_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan1_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan2_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan3_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan4_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan5_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan6_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan7_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan8_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/fan9_input

-r--r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/name

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/of_node -> ../../../../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/ahb/apb/pwm-tacho-controller@1e610000

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm0

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm1

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm10

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm11

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm12

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm13

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm14

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm15

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm2

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm3

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm4

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm5

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm6

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm7

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm8

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 26 22:20 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm9

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Feb 16 08:52 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/hwmon

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4096 Feb 16 08:52 /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/uevent

Comment: can you run view the pwm values in hwmon0 something like. `root@bmc:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0# grep . pwm* `

Comment: Hi, did you cope with the problem? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was because of J80 jumper connected PWM and TACH lines. So, when I removed it pwmtachtool started to work as expected.